# Defined Class won;t recognize

Tags: java, class

I defined a Card class, but when I try to make an object from that class, it isn't recognized. Also, I get an error while printing but I can't tell why or what the error is.

```
public class Card
{
  int castingCost;
  String name;
  int attack;
  int health;
  String spellType;


  public Card(int cost, String title, int offense, int defense, String type)
  {
    castingCost = cost;
    name = title;
    attack = offense;
    health = defense;
    spellType = type;
  }
}

Card queenWanda = new Card(5, "Queen Wanda", 1, 3, "creature");
System.out.println(queenWanda);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be inside a method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Card queenWanda = new Card(5, "Queen Wanda", 1, 3, "creature");
    System.out.println(queenWanda);
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/RGNr9q)

Note that the output may not be what you want since you did not override the `toString` method.